# Xpath in C# : getting element out of a xml "list" (siblings)

Tags: c#, xml, select, xpath

My problem is simple. I'm using XPath to retrieve information from a xml file. My goal is to compare 2 XML files, they should be the same. I have no problem with "single" nodes. My problem comes when there are siblings.

It looks like that :

```
XPathDocument expectedDocument = new XPathDocument("C:\\expected.xml");
XPathDocument testedDocument = new XPathDocument("C:\\tested.xml");
XPathNavigator expectedNav = expectedDocument.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator testedNav = testedDocument.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator expectedIterator;
XPathNodeIterator testedIterator;
string expectedStr;
string testedStr;
string parameter;
parameter = "/DonneesDepot/Identification/@CoclicoFacturation";
expectedStr = expectedNav.SelectSingleNode(parameter).Value;
testedStr = testedNav.SelectSingleNode(parameter).Value;
CompareValues(expectedStr, testedStr, parameter);
```

That works perfectly. Now where it gets complicated is for this kind of XML :

> ```
>   <Surtaxe>
>         <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="1" NbPlisZone="0" PoidsZone="0" />
>         <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="2" NbPlisZone="2" PoidsZone="2" />
>   </Surtaxe>
> ```

I want to be able to make sure the content of "Surtaxe" is the same in both files (keep in mind the order is not important), so I tried this :

```
parameter = "/DonneesDepot/Facturation/Surtaxe/Zone/@PoidsZone";
expectedIterator = expectedNav.Select(parameter);
testedIterator = testedNav.Select(parameter);
while (expectedIterator.MoveNext() && testedIterator.MoveNext())
{
    CompareValues(expectedIterator.Current.Value, testedIterator.Current.Value, parameter);
}
```

But even if the XMLs both contain the two rows, they are sometimes not in the same order, so my while loop doesn't work.

What would be the easiest to compare the two followings (the expected result of this comparison would be "Equality")

```
<Surtaxe>
    <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="1" NbPlisZone="1" PoidsZone="1" />
    <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="2" NbPlisZone="0" PoidsZone="0" />
</Surtaxe>
```

and

```
<Surtaxe>
    <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="2" NbPlisZone="0" PoidsZone="0" />
    <Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe="1" NbPlisZone="1" PoidsZone="1" />
</Surtaxe>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your problem is not "simple", and it is very poorly specified. You can't expect a programmer to write code based on this "specification" of the problem, which is largely based on one example of an input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want, you may need to change it up for your real objects, but this should get you started.  I proveded 2 solutions. A naive n^2 solution and a sorting method that should be faster.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XmlCompare
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Xml.XPath;

    class Program
    {

        private static string xml1 = "<Surtaxe>" + "<Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe=\"2\" NbPlisZone=\"0\" PoidsZone=\"0\" />"
                                     + "<Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe=\"1\" NbPlisZone=\"1\" PoidsZone=\"1\" />" + "</Surtaxe>";

        private static string xml2 = "<Surtaxe>" + "<Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe=\"1\" NbPlisZone=\"1\" PoidsZone=\"1\" />"
                                     + "<Zone CodeZoneSurtaxe=\"2\" NbPlisZone=\"0\" PoidsZone=\"0\" />" + "</Surtaxe>";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var expectedDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml1));
            var testedDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml2));
            var success = true;

            //naive
            foreach (var node in expectedDoc.Descendants("Surtaxe").First().Descendants())
            {
                if (testedDoc.Descendants(node.Name).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString()== node.ToString()) == null)
                {
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //sort
            var sortedExpected = xml1.ToList();
            sortedExpected.Sort();

            var testSorted = xml2.ToList();
            testSorted.Sort();

            success = new string(sortedExpected.ToArray()).Equals(new string(testSorted.ToArray()));

            Console.WriteLine("Match? " + success);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The naive approach works perfectly, it'll get me started for more complicated stuff! (I have the same problem but the first attribute is non significant...). Thank you!